# getText getting called non-stop

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a class which I have defined as an extention of EditText/
I use it to solve the problems we have been having with right-justified hints not appearing.
So, I have written my own code that implements hints internally.

Amongst other, I override the method getText so that it returns null in the case where the value is equal to the hint. Thing is that getText is being called non-stop. It is not called recursively. I put a counter in there and it is definitely exiting one call before performing the next.

```
    @Override
public Editable getText(){
    depth++;
    calls++;
    Log.d("RightJustifiedEditText","getText  - start. Depth =  " + depth + "   calls = " + calls);
    Editable result = (isEmpty?Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(hint):super.getText());
    depth--;
    Log.d("RightJustifiedEditText","getText  - return: " + result + "    Depth = " + depth);
    return result;
}
```

When I run this, the value of "depth" is shown as 1 and then 0 every time.
The value of "calls" just keeps going up.

If I remove "super.getText()" and put a constant in its place then it seems to be ok.

From what I can see in the debug trace it is called from the layout:

```
RightJustifiedEditText.getText() line: 115  
RightJustifiedEditText(EditText).getText() line: 48 
RightJustifiedEditText(TextView).getSelectionStart() line: 5892 
RightJustifiedEditText(TextView).onDraw(Canvas) line: 4057  
RightJustifiedEditText(View).draw(Canvas) line: 6880    
RelativeLayout(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1646  
RelativeLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1373   
TextFieldElement(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1644    
TextFieldElement(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1373 
LinearLayout(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1644    
LinearLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1373 
DoctorSearchElement(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1644 
DoctorSearchElement(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1373  
LinearLayout(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1644    
LinearLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1373 
ScrollView(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1644  
ScrollView(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1373   
ScrollView(View).draw(Canvas) line: 6986    
ScrollView(FrameLayout).draw(Canvas) line: 357  
ScrollView.draw(Canvas) line: 1409  
RelativeLayout(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1646  
RelativeLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1373   
RelativeLayout(View).draw(Canvas) line: 6883    
FrameLayout(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1646 
FrameLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1373  
FrameLayout(View).draw(Canvas) line: 6883   
FrameLayout.draw(Canvas) line: 357  
LinearLayout(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1646    
LinearLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1373 
PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1644   
PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1373    
PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).draw(Canvas) line: 6883 
PhoneWindow$DecorView(FrameLayout).draw(Canvas) line: 357   
PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(Canvas) line: 1862   
ViewRoot.draw(boolean) line: 1522   
ViewRoot.performTraversals() line: 1258 
ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1859  
ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3683    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

This is the layout that directly includes it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<com.applicat.meuchedet.views.RightJustifiedEditText
    android:id="@+id/text_field_element_text_field"
    android:layout_width="170dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textColor="@color/text_field_color"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:paddingRight="15dip"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:background="@drawable/text_field_bg"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_field_element_prompt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    />
```

Comment: I'm guessing here, but are you sure `super.getText()` isn't making it a recursive call?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be because "depth" doesn't get any bigger. Goes up and down between 0 and 1. Also, I am getting the messages "start" and then "return" in order before I get another "start".

Comment: Where's the code calling `getText()` maybe there is a better approach to your problem.

Comment: It is directly from the layout. See update.

Comment: Ok I'm not up with Android, but I'll try and suggest something better than what you are doing.  Does the method need to be overridable? Can you remove the `@overridable' directive and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: It's the same meaning. Override is just for compiler checking. Guarantees that it does exist at a higher level. That way I can be sure I am overriding what I want.